# How to configure docker-compose volume access authorizations

Tags: docker, docker-compose, gitlab, synology

I'm trying to install gitlab with docker and my own docker-compose.yml file on my synology NAS according to the [documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/omnibus/docker/README.html)

When i run this file on my synology (with terminal), i have an error with exited code 1 :

> Ran /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-shell/bin/gitlab-keys
>   check-permissions returned 1

**How can i configure my directory or docker-compose file to correct this error?**

I have execute `chmod -R 777` and `chown -R root:root` on data & logs & config.

```
web:
   image: 'gitlab/gitlab-ce:latest'
   restart: always
   hostname: 'gitlab.example.com'
   environment:
     GITLAB_OMNIBUS_CONFIG: |
       external_url 'https://gitlab.example.com'
       # Add any other gitlab.rb configuration here, each on its own line
   ports:
     - '80:80'
     - '443:443'
     - '22:22'
   volumes:
     - '/srv/gitlab/config:/etc/gitlab'
     - '/srv/gitlab/logs:/var/log/gitlab'
     - '/srv/gitlab/data:/var/opt/gitlab
```

The container exit fail (return 1) with the error below :

> [2019-02-10T08:15:49+00:00] INFO: Running queued delayed notifications
>   before re-raising exception [2019-02-10T08:15:49+00:00] ERROR: Running
>   exception handlers [2019-02-10T08:15:49+00:00] ERROR: Exception
>   handlers complete [2019-02-10T08:15:49+00:00] FATAL: Stacktrace dumped
>   to /opt/gitlab/embedded/cookbooks/cache/chef-stacktrace.out
>   [2019-02-10T08:15:49+00:00] FATAL: Please provide the contents of the
>   stacktrace.out file if you file a bug report
>   [2019-02-10T08:15:49+00:00] FATAL:
>   Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed:
>   execute[/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-shell/bin/gitlab-keys
>   check-permissions] (gitlab::gitlab-shell line 101) had an error:
>   Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed: Expected process to exit with
>   [0], but received '1'
>   ---- Begin output of /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-shell/bin/gitlab-keys
>   check-permissions ---- STDOUT:  STDERR:
>   /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-shell/lib/gitlab_logger.rb:30:in
>   `initialize': Permission denied @ rb_sysopen -
>   /var/log/gitlab/gitlab-shell/gitlab-shell.log (Errno::EACCES)     from
>   /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-shell/lib/gitlab_logger.rb:30:in`
>   open'    from
>   /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-shell/lib/gitlab_logger.rb:30:in
>   `initialize'  from
>   /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-shell/lib/gitlab_logger.rb:120:in`
>   new'     from
>   /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-shell/lib/gitlab_logger.rb:120:in
>   `<top (required)>'    from
>   /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-shell/lib/gitlab_keys.rb:4:in`
>   require_relative'    from
>   /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-shell/lib/gitlab_keys.rb:4:in
>   `<top (required)>'    from
>   /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-shell/bin/gitlab-keys:24:in`
>   require'     from
>   /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-shell/bin/gitlab-keys:24:in
>   `'
>   ---- End output of /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-shell/bin/gitlab-keys
>   check-permissions ---- Ran
>   /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-shell/bin/gitlab-keys
>   check-permissions returned 1

Answer (score 0):

I've replicated your setup and the last output given from docker logs (web_container_id) was

```
=> /var/log/gitlab/gitlab-rails/sidekiq_exporter.log <==
[2019-02-11 17:16:20] 127.0.0.1 - - [11/Feb/2019:17:16:20 UTC] "GET /metrics HTTP/1.1" 200 1298 "-" "Prometheus/2.5.0"
```

Your issue is related to accessing your directory from the user executing docker, since it inherits permissions from the folder and the /srv folder it's a super user folder.

You made the after configurations for docker installation on linux?

https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/linux-postinstall/

Beyond that, **you need to ensure** that your host directory is accessible to the user executing docker-compose, afterwards, it will not work either. You said that you used *chown -R root:root* after a chmod 777? It will cause no effect if you are running without root.

Dockerfile:

```
version: "3"
services:
  web:
   image: gitlab/gitlab-ce:latest
   restart: always
   hostname: gitlab.example.com
   environment:
     GITLAB_OMNIBUS_CONFIG: |
       external_url 'https://gitlab.example.com'
   ports:
     - 80:80
     - 443:443
     - 22:22
   volumes:
     - /srv/gitlab/config:/etc/gitlab
     - /srv/gitlab/logs:/var/log/gitlab
     - /srv/gitlab/data:/var/opt/gitlab
```